# Update gridview inside a partialview modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, modal-dialog, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I am having problems rendering a gridview with pagination on a modal. Whenever I click other pages, it doesn't render the modal at all. Just text with formatting of the next page. For now, these are the only ones I can show but if you need to see a screenshot of the problem, or the controller, I will try to post it.

There is no problem on getting the pagination to working. The only thing is the view. I call the `#modal-container` using an action link from `INDEX` view, and then shows with a gridview data inside. The problem is that when I click the next page of the data, though it goes to the next page, it un-renders all css of the whole page. Just a stripped down formatted-text. How can I update only the gridview?

```
@Html.ActionLink("Transaction History", "TransactionHistory", "AccountBalance", new { accountID = item.AccountID, page = 1, pageSize = 15 },
                               htmlAttributes: new
                               {
                                   onclick = "GetPlayersDetails('" + item.AccountID + "')",
                                   data_target = "#modal-container",
                                   data_toggle = "modal",
                                   @class = "btn btn-xs btn-flat btn-warning"
                               }).If("AccountBalance", "TransactionHistory")
```

Here is the onclick `AJAX` code:

```
function GetPlayersDetails(accountID) {
        console.log('asdasd');
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '@Url.Action("TransactionHistory")', //"/Player/GetPlayersByTeam",  
                        dataType: "html",
                        data: { accountID: accountID },
                        type: "GET",
                        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                            var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
                            toastr.error(err.message);
                            console.log('error');
                        },
                        success: function (data) {
                            $('#qweqwe').html(data);
                            console.log('success');
                        }
                    });
                }
```

Here is the partialview Modal:

```
                <table id="qweqwe" class="table table-hover table-bordered table-striped text-sm ordertable">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th width="35%">Transaction Date</th>
                        <th>Notes</th>
                        <th>Amount IN</th>
                        <th>Amount Out</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="checkboxTable">
                    @foreach (var item in Model.History)
                    {
                        <tr id="tableRow" class="text-center">
                            <td><br />@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TransactionDate)</td>
                            <td><br />@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Notes)</td>
                            <td><br />@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AmountIn)</td>
                            <td><br />@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AmountOut)</td>
                            <td class="text-center actionTD hidden">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

This is the pager on the modal:

```
@Html.PagedListPager(Model.History, page => Url.Action("TransactionHistory",
                                  new
                                  {
                                      accountID = ViewBag.accountID,
                                      page = page
                                  }),
                               PagedListRenderOptions.EnableUnobtrusiveAjaxReplacing(new PagedListRenderOptions
                               {
                                   DisplayPageCountAndCurrentLocation = true,
                                   DisplayItemSliceAndTotal = true,
                                   ItemSliceAndTotalFormat = "Total Records: {2}",
                                   LinkToFirstPageFormat = "First",
                                   LinkToPreviousPageFormat = "Previous",
                                   LinkToNextPageFormat = "Next",
                                   LinkToLastPageFormat = "Last"
                               },
                               new AjaxOptions
                               {
                                   InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                                   HttpMethod = "Get",
                                   UpdateTargetId = "qweqwe"
                               }))
```

This is the action from my controller:

```
public ActionResult TransactionHistory(int accountID, int? page)
    {
        page = page == null ? 1 : page;
        DateTime startDate = Convert.ToDateTime("10-26-2018");
        DateTime endDate = Convert.ToDateTime("10-29-2018");
        var list = BankAccountManagementBusinessLogic.GetDataUpdate(accountID, startDate, endDate, (int)page, pageSize);
        int totalRows = list.Count() > 0 ? (int)list.First().TotalRows : 0;
        var mylist = new StaticPagedList<spGetAccountTransactionHistory_Result>(list, (int)page, pageSize, totalRows);
        TransactionHistorySearchModel searchModel = new TransactionHistorySearchModel();
        TransactionHistoryViewModel model = new TransactionHistoryViewModel(searchModel, mylist);
        ViewBag.accountID = accountID;
        return PartialView(model);
    }
```

Now, these codes work. Displaying the modal and the gridview. The problem is that when going to the next page, the css of the whole page disappears, just a formatted text of the second page is showing. I am unable to find a solution for this yesterday, hoping for an input. Thanks

Comment: where is your gird ? what kind of grid are you using is it a jquery grid or kendo which one ? most of the grid will handle pagination by itself, so no need to write a click event extra for that. and what is qweqwe ?? isit id of the gird or something else ?

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV hi arun, I have updated the question for codes that you need. My only problem is the view is stripped down whenever I go to next page

Comment: just create a div inside your main view. and inside that main view render this partial view. and lets assume the id of that div is myGrid. So once you click on the next page you can get data via ajax and  $('#myGrid').html(data); The method TransactionHistory will return a partial view only in your ajax success you are trying to change content of your partial view table that is wrong.

Comment: <div id="myDiv">@{ Html.RenderAction("ActionName", "Controller", new { Values = "yourvalues" }); }</div> and then indie your ajax   $('#myDiv').html(data); your code will be something like this. try and let me know if you are still facing any issues.